# Identifying connecting elements in an array

Tags: java, performance, recursion, multidimensional-array

So what I am trying to do with this problem is given a grid of numbers I want to have have the location of an even number in the grid and by having that one location it will find all other even elements connected to it.

This picture shows what I am trying to describe. The picture assumes I have the location of **6**
[image]

[image]

here is my code I wrote up I am almost certain that it works I just want to see if there is anyway that I can make it more efficient

```
getLinksEven(grid,0,1);
static void getLinksEven(Server[][] grid, int k, int j)
{
    try{
        if(grid[k-1][j].isEven()&& !grid[k-1][j].isCracked()){
            grid[k-1][j].setCracked(true);
            getLinksEven(grid,k-1,j);
        }

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    try{
        if(grid[k][j-1].isEven()&& !grid[k][j-1].isCracked()){
            grid[k][j-1].setCracked(true);
            getLinksEven(grid,k,j-1);

        }

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    try{
        if(grid[k+1][j].isEven()&& !grid[k+1][j].isCracked()){
            grid[k+1][j].setCracked(true);
            getLinksEven(grid,k+1,j);

        }

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    try{
        if(grid[k][j+1].isEven()&& !grid[k][j+1].isCracked()){
            grid[k][j+1].setCracked(true);
            getLinksEven(grid,k,j+1);

        }

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

}
```

Comment: (I think it would be more intuitive if the 6 were at 1,2 instead of 0,1)

Comment: @cwallenpoole, almost *everything* in computer science uses 0 based indexing.  Using 1 based indexing would *not* be intuitive.

Comment: @SimonC Currently, he is starting from the top left as 0,0 and the lower right is 2,2 (which is why he is using 0,1 for 6). Instead, the lower right should be 0,0. That would make the 6 at the second x index (1), and the third y index (2). Now, you could try to argue that it should be oriented as we orient pixels instead of like we orient coordinate systems, but I am not convinced of that.

Comment: @SimonC Also, it seems that if 0, 1 is 6, then that means he is ordering his numbers y,x. That is clearly against most standard practices.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, my bad, I thought you we were referring to the base of the index.  It would be more intuitive to use x and y for variable names, then pass x first.  However, I think it's arguable to say whether 0,0 should be the bottom right.  I can see why bottom *left* might make more sense though.

Comment: @SimonC D'oh! I meant left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are testing nodes which don't need to be tested:. I'd see four functions for each direction:

```
// you'll need four methods just like this one. This one goes up, you'll need
// one that goes down, another left and a forth right...
static void iterUp(Server[][] grid, int k, int j)
{
    // working with a local variable is easier to read and debug...
    // you may wish to consider it.
    Server cell = grid[k][j]
    if(!cell.isEven() && !cell.isCracked())
    {
        cell.setCracked(true)
        if(k >= 1)
        {
            iterLeft(grid, k-1,j)
        }
        if(k < grid.length - 2)
        {
            iterRight(grid, k+1)
        }
        if(j < grid[k].length - 2)
        {
            iterUp(grid, k, j+1)
        }
        // no point in going down, because we know that down is checked already.
    }
}
```

Then I would define the original function:

```
static void getLinksEven(Server[][] grid, int k, int j)
{
    if(grid.length < k - 1 || grid[k].length < j - 1)
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Not funny.");
    }
    // if this cell isn't even... who cares?
    if(!grid[k][j].isEven()) return;

    // Send the four on their merry way.
    iterUp(grid,k,j);
    iterDown(grid,k,j);
    iterLeft(grid,k,j);
    iterRight(grid,k,j);
}
```

This will save you at least <sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> of your array lookups and possibly as many calls to `isEven()` and `isCracked()`.

Comment: im not sure I understand the code. Since you have and iterDown() iterLeft() and and iterRight() method but none of them have been defined. Also how do we know that down is already checked?

Comment: left right and down would be just like up, only they would move to the left, right, and below.

Comment: You would know that the node below has already been checked because the up method only iterates up (meaning it *has* to have been called from a node which has been checked below it).

Comment: When I submit it to where I am supposed too It still says it is running too slowly. Do you think there is a faster non recursive solution?

Comment: @WillJamieson Have you tried to iterate numerically? That will save time.